# Is there a performance hit using decimal data types (MySQL / Postgres)

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, types, type-conversion

I understand how integer and floating point data types are stored, and I am guessing that the variable length of decimal data types means it is stored more like a string.

Does that imply a performance overhead when using a decimal data type and searching against them?

Comment: Just never use floats for money or currency, ok?

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pavel has it quite right, I'd just like to explain a little.

Presuming that you mean a performance impact as compared to floating point, or fixed-point-offset integer (i.e. storing thousandsths of a cent as an integer): Yes, there is very much a performance impact. PostgreSQL, and by the sounds of things MySQL, store `DECIMAL` / `NUMERIC` in binary-coded decimal. This format is more compact than storing the digits as text, but it's still not very efficient to work with.

If you're not doing many calculations in the database, the impact is limited to the greater storage space requried for BCD as compared to integer or floating point, and thus the wider rows and slower scans, bigger indexes, etc. Comparision operations in b-tree index searches are also slower, but not enough to matter unless you're already CPU-bound for some other reason.

If you're doing lots of calculations with the `DECIMAL` /  `NUMERIC` values in the database, then performance can really suffer. This is particularly noticeable, at least in PostgreSQL, because Pg can't use more than one CPU for any given query. If you're doing a huge bunch of division & multiplication, more complex maths, aggregation, etc on numerics you can start to find yourself CPU-bound in situations where you would never be when using a float or integer data type. This is particularly noticeable in OLAP-like (analytics) workloads, and in reporting or data transformation during loading or extraction (ETL).

Despite the fact that there *is* a performance impact (which varies based on workload from negligible to quite big) you should generally use `numeric` / `decimal` when it is the most appropriate type for your task - i.e. when very high range values must be stored and/or rounding error isn't acceptable.

Occasionally it's worth the hassle of using a bigint and fixed-point offset, but that is clumsy and inflexible. Using floating point instead is very rarely the right answer due to all the challenges of working reliably with floating point values for things like currency.

(BTW, I'm quite excited that some new Intel CPUs, and IBM's Power 7 range of CPUs, include hardware support for IEEE 754 decimal floating point. If this ever becomes available in lower end CPUs it'll be a huge win for databases.)

Comment: The reason is most operations must happen on the CPU rather than be optimized on the FPU. If you need the accuracy of Decimal for storage but not the result of the calculation (ie store 0.1 and 0.2 precisely, but are happy to have 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.300...003) one solution is to duplicate the Decimal table with a table of floats, so the conversion of 0.1 from Decimal to float is done once only. Then calculations use the fast 'float' table. The tradeoff is it takes about twice as much storage.

Comment: @Zero The ideal would be IEEE 754:2008 decimal floating point, which can be done in hardware on some platforms, and supports more efficient fixed-width types. I've investigated adding support for this to PostgreSQL but at this point compiler/toolchain support is a bit immature, and IBM POWER7 / POWER8 CPUs are the only ones with hardware support, so it'd be software for everything else. Your distinction of "on the CPU" vs "on the FPU" is pretty meaningless these days, the FPU is just another unit like the ALU etc. "in software" vs "in hardware" might be clearer, but even then SSE etc...

Comment: Yes: "in software" / "in hardware" is much better (can't edit my original comment after 5 minutes). Main point was to suggest a reasonable trade-off if trying to have 'accurate' storage and still require fast calculation speeds.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. I have one more if you don't mind: If I use numeric type, what precision should I define for a column? Does it have a huge impact? For instance  - I don't think that I will ever operate with numbers larger than 10 in length before the decimal point and I don't need accuracy more than 5 decimal points. So should I limit my column with this constraints, will it have a positive performance impact?

Comment: Precision and scale constraints have no performance impact at all in PostgreSQL. They're purely part of the data model. `NUMERIC` is always stored as binary-coded decimal in the same representation no matter what the precision and scale.

Answer (score 11):

A impact of decimal type (Numeric type in Postgres) depends on usage. For typical OLTP this impact could not be significant - for OLAP can be relative high. In our application a aggregation on large columns with numeric is more times slower than for type double precision.

Although a current CPU are strong, still is rule - you should to use a Numeric only when you need exact numbers or very high numbers. Elsewhere use float or double precision type.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct: fixed-point data is stored as a ([packed BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Fixed-point_packed_decimal)) string.

To what extent this impacts performance depends on a range of factors, which include:

1. Do queries utilise an index upon the column?
2. Can the CPU perform BCD operations in hardware, such as through [Intel's BCD opcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_BCD_opcode)?
3. Does the OS harness hardware support through library functions?

Overall, any performance impact is likely to be pretty negligable relative to other factors that you may face: so *don't worry about it*.  Remember Knuth's maxim, "premature optimisation is the root of all evil".

Comment: I am trying to prove that Postgres will be as capable as MongoDB for a task, so it will make sense to optimize at least somewhat. We seem to be throwing away a lot of relational goodness for the sake or using some hipster technology stack.

Comment: @wobbily_col: in that case send your colleagues to http://thebuild.com/presentations/pg-as-nosql-pgday-fosdem-2013.pdf and http://obartunov.livejournal.com/175235.html

Comment: @Denis I want to keep a schema! The other guys have done some benchmarks to prove MongoDB is the only way to go, but the data is relational, and it seems like a big mistake to me to denormalize it before we even have some solid requirements.

Comment: @wobbily_col ... and MongoDB has some magic super-fast exact, high-range numeric (BCD or IEEE 754 decimal floating point) type? Or are you not really comparing the same thing?

Comment: The data seems to be relational, yet the have chosen Mongo, Node, Express, etc. Some benchmarks have been done, but I think the only relational database they tried was MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

> I am guessing that the variable length of decimal data types means it
>   is stored more like a string.

Taken from MySql document [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)

The document says

> as of MySQL 5.0.3
>   Values for DECIMAL columns no longer are represented as strings that
>   require 1 byte per digit or sign character. Instead, a binary format
>   is used that packs nine decimal digits into 4 bytes. This change to
>   DECIMAL storage format changes the storage requirements as well. The
>   storage requirements for the integer and fractional parts of each
>   value are determined separately. Each multiple of nine digits requires
>   4 bytes, and any remaining digits require some fraction of 4 bytes.

Comment: Why is the answer `NO`?  From the quote you've cited, I would have said that the answer is very much `YES`.

Comment: @eggyal, HOW? I don't understand.

Comment: It is variable length, so its not going to be performed in one CPU operation unless it is one digit.