# Store data as numeric and as double precision

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, numeric

I have a table with a numerical field, say:

```
create table data (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  quantity numeric(21,8) NOT NULL
)
```

I need a `numeric` type because some queries need a level of accuracy that can't be obtained from doubles.

But I also have queries that add up millions of these quantities, don't care about rounding issues and need to be as fast as possible.

Is there a standard strategy to do that or should I just duplicate every numeric:

```
create table data (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  quantity_exact numeric(21,8) NOT NULL,
  quantity double precision NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Have you measured the performance on the numerics?  Is it really that bad compared to the doubles?  Often, when working with "millions of values" in SQL, the time to access the data dominates the processing of the data.

Comment: IMO “need to be super fast” is not an actionable requirement. Get it working with `numeric` first.

Comment: I would be **very** surprised if you can measure the performance gain. And if there is one, I wouldn't be surprised if that is overshadowed by the fact that you are increasing the size of the table and thus the the amount of data that needs to be read during the aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It works fine with numeric - but adding millions of `numeric` is slower than adding millions of `double`s. That is [a fact](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887107/829571) I believe. And performance is critical for some of those queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mean that, even if the numeric fields are not used in the query, the fact that they are part of the table could still affect performance?

Comment: Yes, because each row takes more space and thus fewer rows fit into a single database block. The smallest unit that the database will read is a block. When you have fewer rows per block the whole table consists of more blocks, which means more total I/O to read the whole table. Thus the bigger table is slower to read - although I'm pretty sure you can't measure *that* either in your case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's useful thanks - I'll measure more carefully and come back with additional details.

Comment: I stand corrected. The difference *is* measurable: Summing 10 million numeric values takes about 2.2 seconds on my computer. Summing 10 million float values only takes 1.5 seconds. Given the accuracy problems of `float` I would still stick with `numeric` column until I hit a roadblock with the performance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I expected a larger difference to be honest, thanks for testing. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Please, **read updates below** for a complete view.</sub>

Let's compare both cases you've outlined:

1. use just one column (which one — `float8` or `numeric(21,8)`?) or
2. keep both of them (`keep two`).

Some observations.

1. If both column are kept, we're speaking bout data duplication, which contradicts normalization and introduces ambiguities into the system, that requires special treatment. This makes it `-1` to the `keep two` case.
2. Size of the columns is:

   ```
   SELECT 'float8'::coltyp, pg_column_size(random()::float8) UNION ALL
   SELECT 'numeric(21,8)',  pg_column_size(random()::numeric(21,8));
   ```

   Keeping both column in this case will require nearly twice more space. So `-1` to `keep two` case and also `+0.5` to the `float8` variant, as it's slightly smaller in size.
3. Tests for speed shows the following:

   ```
   SET work_mem TO '2000MB'; -- to avoid usage of temp files
   EXPLAIN (analyze,buffers,verbose)
   SELECT ((random()*1234567)::float8 / 2 + 3) * 5
     FROM generate_series(1,(1e7)::int) s;
   EXPLAIN (analyze,buffers,verbose)
   SELECT ((random()*1234567)::numeric(21,8) / 2 + 3) * 5
     FROM generate_series(1,(1e7)::int) s;
   ```

   On my i7 2.3GHz MBP, I got (based on 5 runs):

   - not more then `3135.238ms` for `float8` and
   - not more then `17325.514ms` for `numeric(21,8)`.

   So here we have a clear `+1` for the `float8` case. This is a memory-only test and querying a table (and a cold one) will require much more time.

It seems, that sticking with `float8` is an obvious way to go (`+1.5` vs `-2`), given your performance requirements. And you can create a view on top of this table that will advertise both, original `float8` and casted `numeric(21,8)` to satisfy your queries with high accuracy requirements.

---

**UPDATE:** After a comment by `a_horse_with_no_name`, I decided to retest, this time using real tables. I went for 9.4beta3, as 9.4 comes with the very nice [`pg_prewarm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgprewarm.html) module.

This is what I did:

```
export PGDATA=$HOME/9.4b3
initdb -k -E UTF8 -A peer
pg_ctl start
```

Then, I've changed some defaults using new [`ALTER SYSTEM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altersystem.html) feature:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers TO '1280MB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET checkpoint_segments TO '99';
ALTER SYSTEM SET checkpoint_completion_target TO '0.9';
```

Restarted the server via `pg_ctl restart` and now the test:

```
SELECT id::int, 1::int AS const, (random()*1234567)::float8 as val
  INTO f FROM generate_series(1,(1e7)::int) id;
SELECT id::int, 1::int AS const, (random()*1234567)::numeric(21,8) as val
  INTO n FROM generate_series(1,(1e7)::int) id;
CREATE EXTENSION pg_prewarm;
VACUUM ANALYZE;
SELECT pg_prewarm('f');
SELECT pg_prewarm('n');
-- checking table size
SELECT relname,pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(oid))
  FROM pg_class WHERE relname IN ('f','n');
-- checking sped
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, verbose) SELECT min(id), max(id), sum(val) FROM f;
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, verbose) SELECT min(id), max(id), sum(val) FROM n;
```

Results are quite different now:

- size is `422 MB` vs `498 MB`
- average time for `float8` is `2272.833ms`
- and for `numeric(21,8)` it is `3289.542ms`

Now, this for sure doesn't reflects real situation, but in my view:

- using `numeric` will add something (for me it is 20%) to the size of relations;
- make queries slower to some degree (for me it is 44%).

I was quite surprised by this figures to be honest. Both tables are fully cached, so time was spent only to process tuples and do the math. I though it'd be a bigger difference.

Personally, I would go for `numeric` type now, given not so big performance difference and data precision it offers.

Comment: Casting the `float` to a `numeric` in a view will not magically make the `float` value accurate. If the source of a value is not correct, simply casting it to a different representation will not fix the problems with the underlying storage.

Comment: In addition, this code may be testing the *conversion* of values to `numeric` versus `float` (and no conversion in the second case), rather than the speed of adding the numbers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, you're correct. I've re-tested on a real tables now.

Answer (score 1):

I add my 5 cents. PG 9.4

```
CREATE TABLE orders( 
count integer not null
...
cost character varying(15) -- cost as string '10.22' for example
ncost numeric(10,2) -- same cost as numeric 10.22
)
```

~260000 rows:

explain analyse

```
select sum(count*ncost) from orders
```

"Total runtime: 743.259 ms" (hot data after 10 tests)
explain analyse

```
select sum(count*cost::numeric(10,2)) from orders
```

"Total runtime: 577.289 ms"
So, keep cost as string  faster for sum().