# Number order ignores decimals in Django Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

Building locally in SQLite. My app has numbers for prices of object. In SQLite I was able to sort prices regulary (ex: $914, $799, $120, $95, 9.00, 7.50.)

After pushing the app to Postgres the numbers come up as such:
95, 914, 9.00, 799, 7.50, 120.

I'm obviously looking to order them by price high to low and low to high in Postgres. What am I doing wrong?

Model Field:

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

URL:

```
url(r'^browse/price_desc/$', 'collection.views.price_desc', name="pricehigh")
```

View:

```
def price_desc(request):
       items = item.objects.all.order_by('-price')

       return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'items' : items,
})
```

Comment: If he is getting his items ordered 95, 914, 9.00, 799, 7.50, 120 as he suggested, then clearly the ordering is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the [decimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) is based on a python [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885023/4024523) on a question about Decimal values, the way postgres store decimals is by a packed BCD string. The way your order is show reflects the order of sorted strings, not numbers.

Not too sure how django implements the sorting of DecimalField, but I am assuming it is sorting it as it would a string.

While the DecimalField seems appropriate for your use-case, you may want to switch to FloatField in order to get the sorting you are looking for.

Comment: Suggesting the use of float for storage when dealing with currency feels like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres stores and orders `NUMERIC` values as you would expect:

```
CREATE TABLE numeric_test (id SERIAL, value NUMERIC(8,2));
INSERT INTO numeric_test (value) VALUES (914), (799), (120), (95), (9), ('7.5');
SELECT * FROM numeric_test;
 id │ value  
────┼────────
  1 │ 914.00
  2 │ 799.00
  3 │ 120.00
  4 │  95.00
  5 │   9.00
  6 │   7.50
(6 rows)
```

I suspect then that your database is not storing as `NUMERIC`. Perhaps your migration is actually creating the column as `TEXT`?

Comment: I think the problem is along these lines. When i first made the model locally the decimal field was a char field. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. I'm obviously new to databases so where would you suggest I start to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you show your migrations file(s)? It's likely it's still being created as a `VARCHAR` or whatever. It _may_ be possible to migrate and fix, but if you are still in earlyish stages, it may be simpler to remove all your migrations for this app and start over.

Comment: I just checked the postgres db and the model does have a CharField. Would you suggest removing the migrations on the production server?

Comment: You _may_ be able to just manually migrate: if your migrations when run normally create the correct table structure, and all migrations are applied, then you probably don't want to remove the migrations and run again.