# Default size of datatype float in mysql - phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have many float columns, But in phpmyadmin I didn't provide the size  of float  but unlike varchar, it still saves the column
[image]

1. what is the default size of float?
2. should I enter the size manually like Float(10,2)  Or it does not make much performance difference ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mysql manual on float](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) says:

> For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric data values should use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION with **no specification of precision or number of digits**.

No length is the default length value.

However, if you do specify length, then mysql will round the float to the number of decimals specified. See the documentation linked above for more details:

> For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.

Comment: Thanks, i will set it to FLOAT(10,2) , I need only 2 digits after decimal point and i won't have more than 10 digits before decimal point.  Thanks :)

Comment: You should consider using decimal or numeric data type in this case

Comment: could you pls explain how numeric datatype will work in this case? thanks

Comment: Go to the link in my answer, then find the numeric data type's description on the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i don't see any big difference for me, i don't need exact values, is there any performance difference between decimal and float?

Comment: Pls do some research before asking lots of follow up questions in comments.

Comment: i really couldn't find, if there is any performance difference, ahhhh forget it, I am thinking too much, 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884405/is-there-a-performance-hit-using-decimal-data-types-mysql-postgres

Comment: Thanks, i will go for float, the values which will be entered in the tables are already round by two decimal after point, and even wrong rounding is acceptable for me , So i think float is right choice for me, Thanks :)